# What's a good test to distinguish past participles from predicate adjectives?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech, adjectives, participles, predicatives

Most past participles can act as predicate adjectives:

"The island was **inhabited**."

but there are some words that may look like both parts of speech, but can only be used in one way or the other:

"The student was **flabbergasted**." 
Flabbergasted is adjectival, but there isn't really a verb "to flabbergast."

"The lazy employee was **fired**."
Fired describes what happened to her (verb), but isn't really a trait she would possess.

So, is there a simple way to test whether a given -ed word is one or the other or both?

Here's what I've come up with and I'd like your assessment:

Put the word in these sentences:

- "the thing seems _____" if it sounds natural, it's a predicate
  adjective.
- "the thing has (been) _____" If it sounds natural, it's a past
  participle -- *been* is used for transitive verbs,
  omitted for intransitive verbs..
- If your word works in both, it can be used either way.

Does that cover my bases, or is there a better way?

Comment: This is English grammar, by the way, not linguistics. And the tests require grammaticality judgements on altered sentences: _He was irritated with/at Jim_ (psychological predicate adjective with prepositional phrase) vs _He was irritated by Jim_ (participle in Passive construction).

Comment: I don't think that there is a mechanical test. You have to decide it by logic.

Answer (score 2):

"very" modifies only adjectives, not verbs: "*John very shot my dog." -> *"My dog was very shot."